# How can I display an image in Python that's represented as an array of bytes without writing it to a file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, temporary-files

I have successfully sent an image through a socket and, on the receiving end, I have the exact same raw bytes that the image file that was sent had. This means that if I binary write those bytes to a file, I'll obtain the same file as the one that was sent. I have tried showing the image from Python without saving it first, but I'm having trouble doing so. If I understand correctly, `matplotlib.imread()` requires the path to a file and then decodes that file into several matrices. Doing something like this works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# data is the image data that was received from the socket

file = open("d:\\image.png", 'wb')
file.write(data)
file.close()

img = mpimg.imread("d:\\image.png")
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Obviously I should use a temporary file for that, but I wrote that just for the sake of the example. Is there any way to call the `imshow()` and `show()` methods without having called `imread()` beforehand, provided I already have those bytes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's OK for you to read from the socket directly, you can convert the socket to a file object using `makefile()`, then provide the socket to `imread` as you would with a regular file. Remember to set the codec when reading:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# don't read from your socket, instead, call this where you would call read
fp = your_socket.makefile()

with fp:
    img = mpimg.imread(fp, format='jpeg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I've searched and couldn't find a way to directly decode images from bytes in matplotlib. If it is not OK to use the above solution because you have already the bytes array, then use `BytesIO` to create a temporary buffer:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import io

fp = io.BytesIO(data)

with fp:
    img = mpimg.imread(fp, format='jpeg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The first solution should work, but it doesn't fit too well with what I'm trying to do with this application. From the client, I request several images which I then either save, or first require to view them and save if wanted. I don't know if I can use your solution with more than one image.
I'm currently trying out the second one.

Comment: I'm getting an exception on imread on your second solution:
py3.8\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 639, in _open
    raise SyntaxError("not a PNG file")
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: not a PNG file

Comment: I used your second solution with Pillow instead of matplotlib and it works! It turns out matplotlib.image.imread() can't take a BytesIO object as a parameter, but the following code worked for me:

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(data))
img.show()

Comment: You have to specify the codec in imread, otherwise it assumes PNG format which is the error you had. Try ``mpimg.imread(fp, format="jpeg")`` if using JPEG. Or the file format you use to encode the image over the socket...